# Python Dictionary For Loop - testing a key against a different list

Tags: python

## Dictionary For Loop

I'm going through the Python Crash Course and came across the following which, while I'm glad it's working but I don't quite understand how it's working...

### Sample

```
favorite_languages = {
 'jen': 'python',
 'sarah': 'c',
 'edward': 'ruby',
 'phil': 'python',
 }

friends = ['phil', 'sarah']
for name in favorite_languages.keys():
  print(name.title())

  if name in friends:
    print(" Hi " + name.title() +
          ", I see your favorite language is " +
          favorite_languages[name].title() + "!")
```

### Output

```
Edward
Phil
 Hi Phil, I see your favorite language is Python!
Sarah
 Hi Sarah, I see your favorite language is C!
Jen
```

### Question

How does favorite_languages[name].title() know to provide the dictionary value 'Python' instead of key 'Phil'?

Comment: because you are using the `name` as the key, ` `favorite_languages[name]` which gives you the corresponding value, which you then call `.title` on

Comment: As an aside, `for name in favorite_languages.keys()` is unecessary, you can just do `for name in favorite_languages:`, iterating over a dictionary object directly iterates over the keys by default.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Perfect, makes sense that name becomes the key. So simple too! Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I edited your question to make the "if" test be part of the loop, which it must be for this code to generate the provided output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if name in friends:
print(" Hi " + name.title() +
   ", I see your favorite language is " +
   favorite_languages[name].title() + "!")
```

The first line filters the `friends` array by testing each element sequentially. So the first item in friends is `"phil"` which is `in friends` so the value "phil" is assigned to the variable `name`.

The print statement then becomes:

```
" Hi " + "phil".title() +
       ", I see your favorite language is " +
       favorite_languages["phil"].title() + "!"
```

And the value of `favorite_languages["phil"] == "python"`

The `if` then tests the other items in the `friends` list against the

Answer (score 0):

`favorite_languages` is a dictionary. The dictionary maps keys, in your case strings, to values, in your case strings as well. 
A foreach loop over a `dictionary.keys()` will loop over all the keys - in this case jen, sarah, edward, phil.

When accessing a dictionary as such `dict[key]`, the corresponding value is returned. `favorite_languages['phil']` for example will return 'python' - this is called a key-value pair. The `title()` function just sets the first character to be upper case.

For a more detailled read about how dictionaries work, refer to https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

Edit: As said above, iterating this way is not the intended way to iterate over a dictionary - the documentation also shows a few examples on how to loop over a dictionary. It's a good exercise to play around with these options a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

```
favorite_languages = {
 'jen': 'python',
 'sarah': 'c',
 'edward': 'ruby',
 'phil': 'python',
 }

friends = ['phil', 'sarah']
for name in favorite_languages.keys():
  if name in friends:
    print(" Hi " + name +
          ", I see your favorite language is " +
          favorite_languages[name] + "!")
```

`.keys()` gets the key as a string, so just use ```favourite_language[name]) to get the item based off the key.

`.title()` just sets the first letter to uppercase. - Use this example without the `.title()` and it just has a lowercase first letter.

In your example you get the value with the key then use `.title()` to uppercase it.